# How to expose my collection from the Web Service (WCF)

Tags: wcf

I have a custom collection which i want to expose from the WCF web service.

```
[DataContract( Name = "MyClass")]
public class MyCollection : IDisposable, List<MyClass> 
{
}
```

When I use `[DataContract( Name = "MyClass")]` attribute it gives error

> Type MyCollection is an invalid collection type since it has DataContractAttribute attribute.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You'll need to use the [CollectionDataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx) attribute to handle this in WCF.

```
[CollectionDataContract] 
public class MyCollection : IDisposable, List<MyClass> 
{
}
```

Marc